# Undo apt-get remove open* ubuntu 12.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu, amazon-ec2

I am running a Linux instance on ec2, snap sorting of image is disabled.

While trying to un-install open-jdk from the system. I stupidly run the command

sudo apt-get remove open*

It started removing many packages, so I stopped the process by CTRL + c.

I did it twice:

- sudo apt-get remove open*
- sudo apt-get remove openjdk*

I stopped the process( CTRL + c) in between for both of them.

Now I see that my other application are not working, because of the packages removed.

Please advice,how can I go back to the state before apt-get remove.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While using the logfiles you might also be able to 'manually' undo, there's an operation worth trying before spending hours on it: `apt-get -f install`
Edit: from debian's man page:

> ```
>   -f, --fix-broken
>       Fix; attempt to correct a system with broken dependencies in place. This option, when used with install/remove, can omit any packages to permit APT to deduce a
>       likely solution. If packages are specified, these have to completely correct the problem. The option is sometimes necessary when running APT for the first time; APT
>       itself does not allow broken package dependencies to exist on a system. It is possible that a system's dependency structure can be so corrupt as to require manual
>       intervention (which usually means using dselect(1) or dpkg --remove to eliminate some of the offending packages). Use of this option together with -m may produce an
>       error in some situations. Configuration Item: APT::Get::Fix-Broken.
> ```

Comment: I run the above menthioned command and i got this output "Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 68 not upgraded." but nothing happened, still i am in the same state.

Comment: @user2058780 Hm, then please provide an example of something failing due to the removal.  Is it something you did not install via apt?